# How to use System.out as an argument in method in java

Tags: java

I have a method in java display,

when i used C++, it seems that I could 
`display(ListNode L, OutputStream out)` but, could I then out `System.out` in it? it seems `out.write` is ok not out.println?

What should I do if I want to use `System.out` as parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the member [System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is of class [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) you could do:

```
void display(PrintStream out) {
    out.println("42!");
}
```

For better visualization of the hierarchy:

```
Object
  |---OutputStream
  |     |---FileOutputStream
  |     |---FilterOutputStream
  |           |---PrintStream (System.out)
  |
  |---InputStream (System.in)
  |     |---FileInputStream
```

To solve the real problem, think about having an interface with two classes which implements it.

For example (without exception handling):

```
interface Display {
    void display(String message);
}

class ConsoleDisplay implements Display {
    void display(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

class FileDisplay implements Display {
    FileOutputStream out;

    FileDisplay(String filename) {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    }

    void display(String message) {
        out.write(message.getBytes());
    }
}

class DoingStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display dispFile = new FileDisplay("logfile.log");
        display("42!", dispFile);

        Display dispConsole = new ConsoleDisplay();
        display("42!", dispConsole);
    }

    static void display(String message, Display disp) {
        disp.display(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there any even bigger stream family than PrintStream, say even contain fileinputStream?

Comment: No! You have to distinguish between input- and output-streams. `PrintStream` is an `OutputStream`. `FileInputStream` is an `InputStream`. So there is no equal super class of both. `FileOutputStream` and `PrintStream` are from same super class `OutputStream`. Like `System.in` and `FileInputStream` are from same super class `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I put OutputStream out parameter, then out.write there is no println right? so that means I could not put outputStream as parameter then put PrintStream there, right?

Comment: That's right! But... you **could** do it like `if (out instanceof PrintStream) { ((PrintStream)out).println("42!"); }`. But this is a bad direction to go. You should explain, what you really want to do. You probably want to have two new classes like `ConsoleDisplay` and `FileDisplay` (or more creative names) and an interface like `Display` with a method `display` to be implemented. Think about!

Answer (score 2):

Type of System.out is PrintStream. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) is the javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to pass `System.out` as a parameter, when it is available everywhere?

Why not just do this:

```
public void display(final String toDisplay) {
    System.out.println(toDisplay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 one might think of method references as well.

Example:

```
private List<ListNode> nodes = new LinkedList<>();

...

nodes.forEarch(System.out :: println);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` instance. `System.out.println` is a method invocation on that instance.
So, you could do the following:

```
public display (ListNode l, PrintStream out) {
    out.println("L is " + l);
}
```